# ClassNotFoundException for GooglePlayServices

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, google-play-services

I have an application that requires GooglePlayServices.

In order to check the the "verify it is installed" code works correctly I uninstalled it.

I then check using GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this).
Problem is I get ClassNotFoundException.

This kinda makes sense since I have removed it. :)

Should something have been included at build time that isn't there?

I have no problem with the build.

Comment: Do you have google-play-services_lib as a library for your project?

Comment: did you update adt to rev 22?

Comment: @Raghunandan At 22. Will try 22.0.1 and see what happens. Also updating PlatformTools to 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have updated adt to rev 22 try the below. This happened to me after updating adt to rev 22. I was using google play services library for google maps.

Right click on your project goto properties. Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. If you have referenced library project. Do the same for the library project also. Clean and Build.

Just in case goto android sdk manager and check that you have the android sdk build tools installed.